# Return true if a single parameter of fact matches rule

Tags: prolog

I'm getting the following error:

```
Singleton Variables: [Month]
```

in SWI-Prolog upon running my file.

I have facts in the format of:

```
weather(Month, Day, Word1, Word2, Word3).
```

and I have the following rule:

```
% Summer: True if Month is jun, jul, or aug
summer(Month) :-
    weather(jun, _, _, _, _);
    weather(jul, _, _, _, _);
    weather(aug, _, _, _, _).
```

I'm new to prolog and don't get why I'm getting an error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `summer(jun). summer(jul). summer(aug).`

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog identifiers starting with capital letters are used as variables, so in your example Month is a variable which is never been instantiated (simply is never used inside the predicate) in summer/1 predicate and that's why it gives you a warning (not error) of Singleton Variable.

In order to fix it you could write something to instantiate variable Month like:

```
summer(Month) :-
    weather(jun, _, _, _, _),Month = jun;
    weather(jul, _, _, _, _),Month = jul;
    weather(aug, _, _, _, _),Month = aug.
```

In the above definition of summer/1 since you write all cases you can see that it is not necessary to use the facts `weather(Month, Day, Word1, Word2, Word3).` since you could rather write:

```
summer(Month) :-
        Month = jun;
        Month = jul;
        Month = aug.
```

Or as @false suggested you could add facts of the form:

```
summer(jun). 
summer(jul). 
summer(aug).
```

Comment: Or even `summer_month(Month) :- member(Month, [jun, jul, aug]).` But I like the fact-based approach suggested by @false better since these are completely fixed relationships. To fill it out more, perhaps `season_month(summer, jun). season_month(summer, jul). ... season_month(autumn, sep)....` etc.